# A word for a person who can "quickly adapt to change"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms, vocabulary

What is a word for (or how would you describe)

A person who can adapt to changes

- in the workplace
- newer technologies
- in requirements for his work

Comment: What words have you found so far?

Comment: What's wrong with adaptable?

Answer (score 3):

As Gandalf states adaptable would fit the bill. So would [***flexible***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flexible).

> (Of a person) ready and able to change so as to adapt to different circumstances:
> *'you can save money if you’re flexible about where your room is located'*

References:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flexible

Comment: To me a flexible person is one who doesn't object to things changing. It refers to the attitude of the individual rather than the ability of the person to adapt.

Answer (score 1):

**Agile**

1. able to move quickly and easily.
2. relating to or denoting a method of project management, used especially for software development, that is characterised by the division of tasks into short phases of work and frequent reassessment and adaptation of plans.

As a software developer using agile as a term of personal characteristic may be misleading due to overlapping meaning. But I have seen and heard that used about a person who can quickly adapt to changes in the work environment. Just make sure the context is correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Adaptive** from **Adaptive Behavior** as [described](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_behavior) as follows:

> "Adaptive behavior is a type of behavior that is used to adjust to another type of behavior or situation. This is often characterized as a kind of behavior that allows an individual to change a nonconstructive or disruptive behavior to something more constructive. These behaviors are most often social or personal behaviors. For example a constant repetitive action could be re-focused on something that creates or builds something. In other words the behavior can be adapted to something else."